# my file upload with mkdir is not working

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I have this code below to upload pdf.

First I see if the pdfs folder exists, if not exists, I create the folder with `mkdir()`, an then when the folder is created I do the upload.

But I'm having an error:

> **Warning: mkdir(): File exists in**  `mkdir($folder.'-'.$year.'/'.$month,0755);`

And then, because of this error, I get other error, because the directory doesn't exist:

> **move_uploaded_file(../pdfs/-2014/05/Food--FROM-2014-08-12-A-2014-05-16.pdf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in**  `$pdf_name = 'Food-'.'-From-'.$date_begin.'-TO-'.$date_end;`

Do you see where can be the error? Because it seems good for me...

```
if(!empty($_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'])){

    $folder     = '../pdfs/';
    $year   = date('Y');
    $month  = date('m');

    if(!file_exists($folder.'-'.$year)){
        mkdir($month.'-'.$year,0755);
    }

    if(!file_exists($pasta.'-'.$year.'/'.$month)){
        mkdir($folder.'-'.$year.'/'.$month,0755);
    }   

    $pdf = $_FILES['pdf'];
    $ext = substr($pdf['name'],-3);
    $f['pdf'] = $year.'/'.$month.'/'.$f['level'].'.'.$ext;


    $pdf_name = 'Food-'.'-From-'.$date_begin.'-TO-'.$date_end;
    move_uploaded_file($pdf['tmp_name'], $folder.'-'.$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$pdf_name.'.'.$ext);
}
```

This is my code updated, with only the mkdir part, where I got the error:

```
if(!empty($_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'])){

    $folder = '../pdfs/';   
    $year   = date('Y');
    $month  = date('m');
    if(!file_exists($folder.$year)){
         mkdir($folder.$year,0755);
     }
```

And Im having the error:
**Warning: mkdir(): No such file or directory in mkdir($folder.$year,0755)**

Comment: Typo? `$pasta` should be `$folder` as far as I can see.

Comment: Why you give a minus point? I dont get it :S

Comment: I didn't but you should change back your code to the original version as the answers below now don't seem to make sense any more. And they did with your original code. I will do it for you.

Comment: You should post the new code with these comments below the original question in an edit. You should also check the exact folder you are in and where you are trying to write to as that can be tricky with relative paths. And you should check the file-permissions of the `pdfs` folder.

Comment: The path is correct, and the pdf folder dont exists yet, I want to create it, when the folder dont exists, that is this case, where Im trying to do the first upload!

Comment: And, my update was only to change '-' to '/'!

Comment: But, after all I'm having the same errors, I was not having, because I create manually the pdf folder!

Comment: Can you post the exact error message you get now? Also, is it possible that there is a file (not a directory) aleady with a number of the month, perhaps created with the previous code?

Comment: Thanks for your help, and now I updated the code with just the part where I have the mkdir error, to get simpler, and because the error is in this part, then upload don´t work, but its because of this first error.

Comment: You need to post the **exact** code you are using and the **exact** error message you are getting. Where do `$pasta` and `$ano` come from?

Comment: Sorry, It is how we say "folder" and "year" in my country, sorry I forget to do the translation!

Comment: I think I found the issue, mkdir creates a directory, not a sequence of them. So I need to have the pdfs folder created first! Now it is working, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

There appear to be a number of problems in the code. But I suspect that the main problem is that you are stating

```
 $folder     = '../pdfs/';
```

and then wanting to test if such things as "../pdfs/-2014" in

```
if(!is_dir($folder.'-'.$year)){
```

And trying to create such oddities as "../pdfs/-2014/5" in

```
    mkdir($folder.'-'.$year.'/'.$month,0755);
```

Most [file systems are sensitive about odd characters](http://linux.dsplabs.com.au/chmod-invalid-mode-dealing-with-a-leading-minus-in-filenames-under-linux-shell-p37/) in file names. I suspect that

- You didn't intend that name to be used
- The file system doesn't like you creating something with a leading minus

BTW: You might want to look at the [recursive parameter on mkdir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) to create the directories in the path. It should reduce the code down a bit

Comment: I update my code. And I just want to create pdfs folder, and then inside this folder I want year, and inside year month, and then I upload pdfs organized from month.

Comment: I got stuck in the same problem, got sorted by passing the recursive parameter as true. i.e mkdir($dir, 0777, true);

Answer (score 0):

Try this        :

```
if(!empty($_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'])){

    $folder     = '../pdfs/';
    $year   = date('Y');
    $month  = date('m');

    if(!is_dir($folder.'-'.$year)){
        mkdir($month.'-'.$year,0755);
    }

    if(!is_dir($folder.'-'.$year.'/'.$month)){
        mkdir($folder.'-'.$year.'/'.$month,0755);
    }   

    $pdf = $_FILES['pdf'];
    $ext = substr($pdf['name'],-3);
    $f['pdf'] = $year.'/'.$month.'/'.$f['level'].'.'.$ext;


    $pdf_name = 'Food-'.'-From-'.$date_begin.'-TO-'.$date_end;
    move_uploaded_file($pdf['tmp_name'], $folder.'-'.$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$pdf_name.'.'.$ext);
}
```

Comment: What change did you make from the OP's code to fix the problem? A 20+ line code dump with no mention of what's different is not very helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have the same problem with !is_dir.